# How to sort out NSArray to only get content with specific strings

Tags: ios, string, sorting, nsarray

I think I have a tough task, thats why I ask this question. I have an long `NSArray` with a huge amount of Strings inside. The point is, I only want to have strings in my array witch contain .app. Is there a way to loop though the array, check if the string at a specific index contains .app and if not remove the string from the array, so I only have strings with .app in my,

Example:

This is my example array (hello, this, is, a test application, called, NSArraySort.app)

So in this case I only like to have the last item "NSArraySort.app"

I think the answer is a `for` loop, but I don't know how to make this.

Comment: So you already thought about looping. What research have you done around that and filtering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *str in myArray) {
    if ([str rangeOfString:@".app"].location != NSNotFound) {
        [results addObject:str];
    }
}

NSLog(@"results = %@", results);
```

If you just want strings that end with `.app` then use:

```
if ([str hasSuffix:@".app"]) {
```

Comment: Thanks, I never thought it would be that simple it works flawlessly